# Export WAS profile from linux

Tags: linux, websphere

I have WAS instance in Linux. I have to move the WAS instance profile to Windows. 
Can anyone let me know how to export the configurations,profiles from Linux. How to generate *.car file from Linux.

I have tried `$AdminTask.exportWasprofile(['-archive', '/home/user'])` and different combinations of passing arguments.
I get  `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token -archive`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When using this command you need to specify the *.car file explicitly. For example, to export to a file called "cell.car" try using the following syntax:

```
AdminTask.exportWasprofile(['-archive', '/home/user/cell.car'])
```

This is documented in the [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_atconfigarchive.html#rxml_atconfigarchive__cmd3).